# I am getting this kind of error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at deviceToken.then.result (/srv/index.js:14:33)" at node.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my code:

```
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/users/{sender_user_id}/token_id`).once('value');

    return deviceToken.then(result => {
        const token_id = result.after.data();

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "New message!",
                body: "You have a new message!",
                icon: "default"
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {
            return console.log('This was a notification');

        });
    });


});
```

And I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
>       at deviceToken.then.result (/srv/index.js:14:33)

I am to retrieve device token id from users. How would I do that?

node --version: v12.4.0
npm --version: 6.9.0

Comment: What do you get when you console.log(result)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`once`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) method inside [`firebase.database.Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference) returns a `Promise<DataSnapshot>`. The class [`admin.database.DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot.htm) does not contain a property called `after`. If you are trying to retrieve the `token` from the database then change the following:

```
    return deviceToken.then(result => {
        const token_id = result.after.data();
```

into this:

```
    return deviceToken.then(result => {
        const token_id = result.val();
```

From the docs:

> [`val`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot.html#val)
>
> Extracts a JavaScript value from a DataSnapshot.
>
> Depending on the data in a DataSnapshot, the `val()` method may return a scalar type (string, number, or boolean), an array, or an object. It may also return null, indicating that the `DataSnapshot` is empty (contains no data).